# In C#, how can I set the background color cell of exported Excel file to particular color based on some conditions?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am using following reference to insert data into Excel. Based on the codes below, I want to set the cell color which will also contain some data (like Score)

```
using ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook;

XLWorkbook workbook;
workbook = new XLWorkbook(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Template.xlsx"));
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1);

foreach(var item in output)
{
    var cellname = ...... //  some codes to get cell name For exampple : it gets A5
    worksheet.Cell(cellname).SetValue(item.Score);

    // Now I need to set color for cell A5 (ie cellname) based on some condition
    // item will also contain parameter Color which will have color name like below

    if(item.Color == "Red")
        worksheet.Cell(cellname).SetColor(Red);     // I need proper code to be written in this line
    else if (item.Color == "Green")
        worksheet.Cell(cellname).SetColor(Green);  //

    // ............ some other codes .......
}
```

I am using [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) so I need code that will work with this reference.
Also, item.Color is received from DB so its value can be any between Red, Green or Blue, therefore I need to check item.Color value and accordingly set the cell color.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the nicest thing you can do would be to add conditional formatting in the Excel file itself. That way, Excel will apply the color and will do so even when the values change after you've generated the file. This is described in [this part of the documentation](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Conditional-Formatting):

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.AddWorksheet("Sheet1");

ws.FirstCell().SetValue(1)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(1)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(2)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(3)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(4);

ws.RangeUsed().AddConditionalFormat().WhenBetween(2, 3)
  .Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red);
```

To just set the text or fill color, again, you can look at the documentation for [fill color](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Styles-Fill) or [font](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Styles-Font):

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Style Fill");

var co = 2;
var ro = 1;

ws.Cell(++ro, co + 1).Value = "BackgroundColor = Red";
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;

ws.Cell(++ro, co + 1).Value = "PatternType = DarkTrellis; PatternColor = Orange; PatternBackgroundColor = Blue";
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.Fill.PatternType = XLFillPatternValues.DarkTrellis;
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.Fill.PatternColor = XLColor.Orange;
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.Fill.PatternBackgroundColor = XLColor.Blue;

workbook.SaveAs(Styles_Fill);
```

In general, the [documentation](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki) does seem fairly comprehensive and helpful.

Comment: Thank you but this will not fulfill my requirement. I get item.Color value from DB. Therefore I need to use something like this:
    if(item.Color == "Red")
    worksheet.Cell(cellname).SetColor(Red);   as stated in my question

Comment: @Amrit: Then use the second approach? You will need a mapping between your color strings and the constants/objects ClosedXml uses, but that's probably to be expected.

Comment: @Amrit Yes, use conditional formats. Further, you can use `XLColor.FromName` to deduce the color object, e.g. `XLColor.FromName("Red")`. I also want to urge you to read through the ClosedXML documentation. It will answer many questions that you will encounter as you learn ClosedXML.